# How to use a global key outside the file widget had been defined

Tags: flutter, dart, key

In file1 I'm defining the following widget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidget createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}
```

In file2 I want to call this widget and give a global key for the key parameter. To do so I'm importing file1:

```
import 'package:mypackage/supplemental/file1.dart';
```

Then in this file (file2) I want to define a MyWidget global key:

```
GlobalKey<_MyWidgetState> globalKey;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> The name '_MyWidgetState' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type
>   argument. Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a
>   type named '_MyWidgetState'

How come I cannot access it even though I imported the file?

Comment: If you have a ```_``` before a class or a variable declaration, it means that class or variable is private. In your case ```_MyWidgetState``` is private and can't be accessed from a different file. You can remove the ```_``` from the class declaration and then it should work.

Answer (score 9):

Remove the underscore from in front of your _MyWidgetState to make it public. Change

```
_MyWidgetState
```

to

```
MyWidgetState
```